# laravel 5.7 Relationships belongsto hasmany error

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel, I'm beginning with laravel 5.7. I have two model.

Modelo categoria:

```
class categoria extends Model
{
    public function indicadores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Indicador');
    }
}
```

Modelo Indicador:

```
class Indicador extends Model

    {
        public function categoria()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\categoria');
        }
    }
```

In the controller, I look for all Indicador

```
class IndicadorController extends Controller {

       public function index() {       
         $indicadores = DB::table('indicadors');
        return view('indicador.index', ['indicadores' => $indicadores]);
    }
```

When I try to show the category to which the indicador belongs,

```
 <tbody>
                    @foreach ($indicadores as $indicador)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $indicador->categoria->nombre }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach    
                </tbody>
```

I get the following error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$categoria (View:resources\views\indicador\index.blade.php)

And I don't understand why. Thanks in advance

Comment: In your controller, try giving this a shot instead: `$indicadores = Indicador::with('categoria')->get();`

Comment: thank you for answer so soon. Very useful answer for me

Answer (score 1):

Using the DB facade returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

so the relationship will not be accessible.

You instead want an `Eloquent` model instance which you can use the model directly:

```
use App\Indicador;
...
$indicadores = Indicador::all();
```

or as [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/899126/chris-forrence) suggests, eager load:

```
$indicadores = Indicador::with('categoria')->get();
```

Comment: thanks you for answer so soon. Very useful answer for me

Comment: @ymoya No problem. If you find that this answer was the correct one please mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eloquent instead of the query builder:

```
class IndicadorController extends Controller {

    public function index() {       
        $indicadores = Indicador::all();
        return view('indicador.index', ['indicadores' => $indicadores]);
    }

}
```